# What would Nietzsche think of Taoism?

Tags: nietzsche, taoism

I'm not too familiar with the works of Nietzche (*The Gay Science*, *On the Genealogy of Morals*, etc). However, I am familiar with the terms of overman or Ubermensch, a person who creates new morals/traditions apart from herd mentality and who inspires others to be like him, better stated as a "Caesar with Christ's soul".

Given this idea of Ubermensch, how would it fit in with the idea of Taoism and ceding one's "knowledge", embracing the unnameable Tao, and "plac[ing] yourself behind [others]"?

Comment: there's probably some book length studies on this. there is on existential stuff and buddhism. heidegger and nietzsche too. as well as the kyoto school, zen (so tao influenced) buddhists who engaged with the tradition of western philosophy. i really liked nishitani...

Comment: obviously some traditions, perhaps more obviously Confucianism, quite different tho surely cross pollinated with taoism, were influential in modernism / the avant garde, which, in turn, is what may be the most interesting aspect of nietzsche's legacy

Comment: Maybe useful : [Nietzsche and Asian Thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nietzsche_and_Asian_Thought).

Comment: And also [Nietzsche, Heidegger, and Daoist Thought](http://www.sunypress.edu/p-4268-nietzsche-heidegger-and-daoist-.aspx).

Comment: He would probably consider Taoism as "slave morality", designed to glorify weakness and loss of self-identity.